# Page containing vertically centered and bottom-aligned items

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have a specification that requires text to be vertically centered on a page and an image bottom aligned on the same page.  To accomplish this effect, I use the following, using `\vspace*{\fill}` to get the vertical text alignment, and `\vspace{-4cm}` to ensure that the text is centered on the page (and not centered in the whitespace above the image).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
Here is some vertically centered text
\vspace*{\fill}
\vspace{-4cm}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm,figheight=4cm]{Testing a long text string}
\end{document}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this effect without hard-coding the image height?

[image: This is the desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `\smash` the image object, then you don't have to worry about it's height:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
Here is some vertically centered text

\vspace*{\fill}
\vspace*{-4cm}
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm,figheight=4cm]{Testing a long text string}

\newpage

\vspace*{\fill}
Here is some vertically centered text

\vspace*{\fill}
\smash{\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm,figheight=4cm]{Testing a long text string}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach also eliminates the horizontal centering of the figure.  Is there a method that maintains the horizontal centering?  I tried `\makebox[0pt][c]{...}` but it does not give the desired effect.

Comment: @canzar: Use `\mbox{..}`.

Comment: This works beautifully, but I don't understand why LaTeX centers the `\mbox{...}` but not the 0x0 box resulting from the smash.  Do you know why it works this way?